'error sending request for url' with command "cargo build-sbf"
My error is slightly different from the ones previously stated in the forum. Upon running "cargo build-sbf", i get the error "[2024-04-03T16:51:26.963362217Z ERROR cargo_build_sbf] Failed to install platform-tools: error sending request for url (https://github.com/solana-labs/platform-tools/releases/download/v1.37/platform-tools-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2): operation timed out".
The error is so consistent and I can't seem to be able to troubleshoot it.

It looks like you have a connection issue. Be sure that your machine is connected to the internet and can make calls out to the internet. Or perhaps your internet connection doesn't allow you to download large files.

The error you're encountering indicates that the attempt to download the platform-tools from GitHub timed out. This is often caused by network connectivity issues or a temporary service disruption on GitHub, you can try these steps:
Manually Download the Platform Tools

Navigate to the platform-tools releases page on GitHub.
Download the platform-tools-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 file for Linux x86_64 systems (or the appropriate file for your system).
Manually extract the downloaded file to the directory expected by cargo build-sbf.

Configure a Timeout Extension
If you suspect that the download timeout is due to a slow network, you can extend the timeout setting in your Cargo configuration file (.cargo/config.toml), as follows:
[net]
git-fetch-with-cli = true
timeout = 300 # Timeout in seconds

Check Firewall and Proxy Settings
If you are behind a corporate firewall or using a VPN or proxy, ensure that they are not blocking GitHub. You may need to configure your firewall or proxy settings to allow downloads from GitHub
If after following these steps the issue remains unresolved, it might be beneficial to check with your network administrator or ISP to identify if there are additional network restrictions
